# How do I map a movieClip to another movieClip which has its rotationX modified?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d

I have a movie clip which I have set its `rotationX` property to -45. This gives the illusion of 3d. It is skinny in the back and fat in the front. I now want to add thumbnail clips on top, but can't figure out how to translate the original clip's `x` and `y` properties back to the 2d world.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can solve this problem by using the localToGlobal method of the movieclip.

Let's say m is your movieclip, and you have set

```
m.rotationX = -45;
```

Now you want to know, what point on the stage is the (10, 10) of m.
For this use localToGlobal:

```
var point:Point = m.localToGlobal(new Point(10, 10));
```

And there you go. point.x and point.y will be the coordinates you can use on the stage.